# TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException not firing because of a switch case

Tags: c#

Using the .Net Framework 4.8 and VS 2022, in the following program, UnobservedTaskException is raised correctly

```
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Listen to UnobservedTaskException
            TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;

            // Launch a task that will throw an exception
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("boom");
            });

            // Run the GC periodically so that UnobservedTaskException gets triggered
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(500);
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                }
            });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

However in this slightly different one that should behave exactly the same (the Console.Readline() is now wrapped by a switch statement), the UnobservedTaskException is not triggered. What am I missing ?

```
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Listen to UnobservedTaskException
            TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;

            // Launch a task that will throw an exception
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("boom");
            });

            // Run the GC periodically so that UnobservedTaskException gets triggered
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(500);
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                }
            });

            string dummy = "whatever";
            switch (dummy)
            {
                default:
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private static void TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: your program is exiting in the switch case; whereass the background threads stay alive due to the blocked `ReadLine` call.

Comment: No, because of ```Console.ReadLine()```, in both cases my program is not exiting as long as I don't hit a key.

Comment: I cannot reproduce, also in the second case, I see the exception.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference, the `switch` is trivially optimized to the plain statement. This might be a debugger issue, or a miscompilation. What is the exact version of the compiler in use? You should be able to get that from the build output. You can also verify the output in either case with a tool like ILSpy.

Comment: Asynchronous main methods are really helpful just FYI.

Comment: @KlausGütter thanks for the feedback. I double checked with a colleague and she was able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DanielA.White it is called correctly in the second example. Did you try to execute the code ?